How much fuel does the SpaceX HLS need to do a round trip? Want to estimate the number of launches needed to refuel HLS

This image is from the all-hands meeting, right before IFT4 Musk announced Starship 2 and Starship 3. I know he likes to keep the imaginary pipeline going, all well and good, investors like to see a bright future!
In that meeting though, he dropped a bit of a bombshell for me (which I don't think anyone else has really focused on). Whilst discussing his outlines, he mentioned the ACTUAL performance of IFT3 (that is, its payload to orbit) in IFT3 configuration, was 45t. (I added that in red).
For IFT5 the plan (as I understand it) is to use tiles that are twice as strong and to add a silicon carbide blanket (that's another 5-8 tonnes in my opinion) to protect the ship in case some tiles come loose. I plan to assume for my calculations that these changes will double the mass of the thermal protection system and that this extra weight will further reduce the 45-ton payload capability.
Now I would like to estimate the number of refilling launches needed for Starship HLD as a function of the tanker-Starship's payload capacity. To do this, I need to estimate how much fuel and oxidizer must be delivered to refill Starship HLS while it's in Low Earth Orbit (LEO).
I assume that the first step would be to calculate a delta-v budget from LEO to the moon's surface and back for the Starship HLS mission architecture. Another aspect would be estimating the rate of propellant boil-off during various phases of the mission.
I realize that some of the input parameters (such as Starship HLS's dry mass, the boil-off rate, and the duration of the stay on the moon's surface) are unknown at this time so we'll need to state some (reasonable) assumptions for the time being until we know more. I'm more interested in learning how to do these calculations than I am in knowing the exact result.

In the absence of actual hard numbers from SpaceX, a company quite reasonably careful with facts this is an opinion question that will be outdated quickly, possibly within weeks. Space shuttle, Buran and X37 all suggest the core concept is possible but hard, and the devil in the details. A guess would be a payload between half and third the starting number. Separately would strongly advise not considering yourself a 'we' with any business enterprise you are not manager/shareholder of.

Yeah, but this was a fact chucked out by Elon! IFT3 45t to orbit, IFT4 is heavier, IFT5 is even heavier and that mass is on the starship not superheavy which has an outsized impact on payload.
I changed the "we" ✔️ comment, and to make this less "opinion" I've also changed the title.

There's likely a whole lot of context you have in your head which you forgot to put into the question, so it does not make all that much sense. What is "the Artemis mission" that you are talking about? The only currently planned role of Starship in the Artemis program is as the HLS (lunar lander), for which payload to LEO is hardly relevant. Also, an early flight test article is unlikely to be very similar to the final production version in terms of performance numbers.

Agreed, it happens to me a lot! The HLS will need to be refueled every time it lands, so It has to come back to LEO, and Starship needs to do multiple launches to refuel it. So I guess the more accurate question is how much fuel weight does the HLS need to do the round trip, LEO to Moon surface and back, and how many launches of Starshiip from Earth to LEO is that for different payloads.

It might be useful to do a little bit of research before asking a question. Just a couple of examples: "which I don't think anyone else has really focused on" – Only just about every space-related YouTube channel, website, or X user.  "IFT4 added that huge interstage" – No, it did not. That was added between IFT 1 and Flight 2. "Does anyone know how heavy that is" – Yes, everybody knows how heavy that is because it is part of publicly available regulatory filings such as the launch license and the environmental assessment.

Starship is still in development and will likely constantly evolve over the next several years. Falcon 9 and Merlin steadily increased in capability, and the same will probably happen with Starship and Raptor. What the end result capability and capacity will be say ten years from now who knows. As for HLS I expect the landers will probably be  expendable for Artemis, left in lunar or heliocentric orbit or crashed onto the lunar surface for seismic readings.

HLS as currently configured can't return to Earth's surface as it has no heat shield. It might be possible to return it to LEO but this would require more propellent and a lot of dips into the atmosphere that would take some time to complete.

The July 2024 answer to the question of 'how much fuel does HLS need' appears to be 1500 tonnes (if you trust internet sleuths measuring tanks sizes from pictures), which per the Question is a problem if payload is under 50 tonnes, meaning very large numbers of launches and need very low per flight costs to make sense against even SLS.
Link above is to a lengthy post triggered by same Musk statements as the question and includes a number of relevant sources for state of public information at that time.
This is however still early and numbers for the lander AND the tanker payloads easily go either way, with good odds of both - things that fail needing heavy fixes, things that work getting trimmed or run harder.
Regardless of affairs with Starship, assuming SpaceX can actually convert hovering onto a target over the ocean into reliable chopstick landings the Superheavy first stage plus large scale engine production line is still a very interesting capability to have for major Lunar program, even if operating it with expendable upper stages turns out to make more sense.

It is too early to accurately estimate the exact size of Starship HLS's tanks, Starship HLS's weight, or even the material that it will be made of. Because it does not need to survive reentry, most of the reasons for choosing stainless steel that Elon Musk described in an interview do not apply to StarShip HLS. It might make sense to build it out of a material with higher specific strength than Stainless Steel, such as an aluminum-lithium alloy (like Falcon 9) or carbon-fiber composites (which was the original plan for Starship).
We can estimate the delta-v budget for the round trip and then use the rocket equation to ballpark the ratio of initial mass, $m_0$, to final mass, $m_f$. (Note: This won't be perfectly accurate because mass will be lost due to boil-off and some payload will be left on the moon's surface, but let's start with the simplest possible calculation and see where it leads us.)
To estimate the delta-v required for the mission we can start by using a delta-v map.

The values on this map will give us a rough idea of the delta-v requirements, but the total delta-v for an actual mission will vary depending on many factors including when the mission is launched, the exact altitude of the LEO orbit around the Earth, where the lander sets down on the Moon, etc.
However, we can add up the values circled in red and multiply by two for the round trip...
$${\text{total-delta-v}}=(3.12+0.14+0.68+1.72)*2=11.32 km/s$$
Note: In practice, the delta-v for the landing on the moon will be higher than the delta-v for taking off from the moon since the landing will probably be more judicious and will therefore incur more gravity losses.
Another factor we should consider is the possibility of Starship HLS aerobraking when it returns to Earth. I have seen no evidence of such a plan for Starship HLS, but it is a technique that other mission architectures use. For now, let's assume that Starship HLS brakes propulsively when it returns to LEO. Update: In a recent interview with Tim Dodd, Elon mentions this but isn't clear about what the plan is (ref).
To estimate $m_0 \over m_f$ using the rocket equation, we need to know the exhaust velocity of the vacuum engines. This is a value that we can't know for sure. Aspirational values are floating around on the Internet, but for a human-rated mission, there will need to be some margin between the ISP that the engine achieves when it's on the verge of exploding and the ISP at which it can be operated safely. During a landing burn, the engines will need to throttle up and down so, on average, they won't be operated at their theoretical peak performance. There will also be losses associated with start-up and shut-down at the start and end of each burn. Keeping all this in mind, a 2019 tweet from Musk claimed that the vacuum-optimized Raptor will achieve ~380 ISP, which would equate to an exhaust velocity of 3727 m/s.
If we plug the raw numbers into the rocket equation, we get
$${m_0 \over m_f}=exp({\Delta v \over v_{exhaust}})=exp({11320 \over 3727})=20.85$$
If we apply a 10% safety factor to the exhaust velocity value we get
$${m_0 \over m_f}=exp({\Delta v \over v_{exhaust}})=exp({11320 \over (3727*0.9)})=29.2$$
If we apply a 20% safety factor to the exhaust velocity value we get
$${m_0 \over m_f}=exp({\Delta v \over v_{exhaust}})=exp({11320 \over (3727*0.8)})=44.6$$
(I will use the most optimistic value of ${m_0 \over m_f}=20.85$ from here on to keep things simple.)
Based on the size of Starship, and the fact that it burns liquid CH4 and liquid O2, we know that it was filled up completely, the mass of propellant would be on the order of 1,200,000 kg. In fact, according to this article

The way Musk described it, having the ability to refuel a Starship means it can carry a full 1200-ton propellant load when leaving Earth's orbit.

We can now use ${m_0 \over m_f}$ and the rough propellant mass estimate to calculate $m_f$.
$${m_0 \over m_f}=20.85={m_f+1.2e6 \over m_f}$$
Rearranging we get..
$$m_f = 60457 kg$$
I have seen estimates of the second stage dry mass of Starship that are as high as 100,000 kg. This value does not include payload and propellant loss due to boil-off. One way to interpret this information is that Starship HLS will not only be a custom design of Starship, but it will also be a significant redesign to achieve the required mass ratio - likely quite different from the stainless steel Starship used for IFT4.
It would be illogical to design a customized Starship HLS and then operate it in a manner that involves not fully fueling it when it's in LEO. Doing so would mean that mass was being wasted on oversized tanks instead of being allocated to the payload.
If your goal is to estimate the number of refilling launches, I think it makes sense to assume that Starship HLS will be completely filled at the start of each mission and that the mass of fuel needed for that will be at least 1200 tons. The estimate made by the article referenced in the earlier answer, which stated...

Recent renderings suggest that the lunar lander will be slightly taller, with a propellant load of approximately 1,500 tons.

...is certainly plausible.
Update: @StevePemberton pointed out that the plan might be to end the mission after returning the astronauts to lunar orbit. In that case, the delta-v would be...
$${\text{total-delta-v}}=3.12+0.14+(0.68+1.72)*2=8.06 km/s$$
Mass ratios would be...
$${m_0 \over m_f}=exp({\Delta v \over v_{exhaust}})=exp({8060 \over 3727})=8.69$$
If we apply a 10% safety factor to the exhaust velocity value we get
$${m_0 \over m_f}=exp({\Delta v \over v_{exhaust}})=exp({8060 \over (3727*0.9)})=11.2$$
If we apply a 20% safety factor to the exhaust velocity value we get
$${m_0 \over m_f}=exp({\Delta v \over v_{exhaust}})=exp({8060 \over (3727*0.8)})=14.93$$
$${m_0 \over m_f}=8.69={m_f+1.2e6 \over m_f}$$
Rearranging we get...
$m_f = 155972 kg$ (best case), or
$m_f = 86157 kg$ ($v_{exhaust} = 3727*0.8$ case)
So, with this approach, Starship HLS (expendable) could be more similar to the stainless steel Starship used in IFT4.
Still, the original conclusion stands. For a lunar mission, Starship HLS will need to be completely filled up in LEO.

With the schedule pressure SpaceX is facing for HLS it's hard to imagine them throwing a huge wrench into their process by changing to a different material. Also there is no requirement by NASA to return the lander to LEO, so I don't see why they would add that burden to themselves either. I’m sure long term SpaceX plans for more sustainable methods, but for now I’m guessing they just want to do what they are being contracted to do as quickly and reliably as possible. Just my opinion but it seems like it would be relatively safe to make those assumptions for your calculations. Fully fueled yes

Interesting point - it did not occur to me that the Starship HLS would not be reused.
